# Youtube API response data

Tags: ajax, json, api, parsing, youtube

Youtube's API documentation seems to me to be complete rubbish, I've spent hours reading through it and can't seem to figure out how to display a simple thumbnail of a video even by just test-copy-and-pasting the code they give in a few examples. Could someone maybe explain or point me in the direction of an at least half decent tutorial of how to retrieve data from a video search query?  Using JSON by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've disregarded the youtube api and just made my own thumbnails using imagemagick with node, but it doesn't sound like you're using node.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the JSON response into this [JSON to CSV](https://json-csv.com) converter, you can open the CSV file in a spreadsheet.  Within the spreadsheet you will have lots of tools to help you parse the data.